# What is the difference between 'at Christmas' and 'on Christmas'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases

I saw the sentence like 'I will go on a vacation at Christmas'.

Could I substitute this sentence with 'I will go on a vacation on Christmas'

If so, What is the difference between 'at Christmas' and 'on Christmas'?

I'd like to know the difference.

Answer (score 11):

For me (British), I would never say "on Christmas", because 'on' is used with a day, not a period. I would say "on Christmas Day", or "on New Year's Day", or "On Easter Sunday" but "at Christmas" or "at Easter".

Answer (score 7):

**Christmas** can be understood to be a particular day (December 25) or a seasonal celebration similar to *Yule*. Hence, the different prepositions, **on** for the day,  **at** for the seasonal celebration.

In my experience, the phrase is usually "on Christmas *day*".

> She is visiting her family on Christmas day, and then she's leaving with her
>   friends to go on a ski trip.
>
> He plans to propose to her, but he wasn't sure it would be a good idea
>   to do so at Christmas or to wait until spring.

Comment: Also "for Christmas" can be used to be less specific about the visit date, and instead refer generally to the Christmas season.

Comment: While “on Christmas day” is hardly unusual, I would say that just “on Christmas” is the more frequently-heard expression, by a considerable margin. Might be a cultural thing, though (my experience is the American Northeast for the most part).

Comment: @KRyan: I'm from southeastern PA.  Please use **on Christmas** in a sentence, and we'll see if we have a similar ear.

Comment: “I’ll see my family on Christmas.”

Comment: @KRyan apparently, some Americans (and maybe some British people also)  omit the "Day" bit. [*"We went to a movie on Christmas because everything else was closed."*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44836/44619)

Comment: @Mari-Lou Yeah, that sounds quite natural to me. Adding “Day” would make it sound a bit over-formal to my ear.

Comment: @KRyan but nevertheless the "on Christmas" refers to the actual date, not the festive season. Right?

Comment: @Mari-Lou Oh yes, it’s definitely just an omission of Day. Likewise “at Christmas” would be an omission of “celebration” or similar, an event. Neither, to me, would refer to the season. I don't think I hear people talk about the season as much, but “over” is the proposition for that to me.

Answer (score 4):

### on

In English the preposition *on* is normally used for days of the week, dates, and holidays which fall on specific dates, e.g., Independence Day (Fourth of July)

- I'm going away **on** Friday
- We're flying to Philadelphia **on** December 23rd
- We'll be opening our gifts **on** Christmas Day.
- They will be flying back **on** New Year's Day

In American English, *on* is used before the expression *weekend*

- Things to do in Philadelphia **on** the weekend

### at

In English, the preposition *at* is normally used for the time of day, festive periods; and in British English before the word *weekend*.

The **Christmas Season** (also called *[Happy Holidays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_and_holiday_season#Happy_Holidays)*) basically covers a period of three days: Christmas Eve (24th December), Christmas Day (25th December), and  St Stephen's Day (26th December). Likewise, **Easter** is celebrated over three days in Anglophone countries: Good Friday, Easter Sunday, and Easter Monday. When speaking about the Christmas or Easter holidays/period,  the preposition *at* is preferred.

- **At** nine o'clock in the morning, we arrive in Philadelphia.
- We're visiting friends and relatives **at** Christmas (the holiday period)
- This year, Christmas falls **at** the weekend.

UPDATE

From  the website [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm) it appears that in some English dialects, the expression **on Christmas**, is commonly used. However, I would not use this particular structure in a formal setting, or if one had to sit an English language exam.

It is nevertheless a very interesting observation, and something I would have thought not possible until today.

> [image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is right; I’m American and your example of “on the weekend” doesn’t sound right. And in any event, to me “at Christmas” would not refer to the Christmas season, but rather to a Christmas celebration, probably on Christmas itself.

Comment: @KRyan please see Google link: [things to "on the weekend"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=things+to+%22on+the+weekend%22) In BrEng "at Christmas" used this way is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just as on Christmas is short for on Christmas day,....(John Lawler)

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner but note Khan, Colin Fine, and TRomano's answers, none of whom have said "on Christmas" is acceptable, and neither would have I if it hadn't ben for KRyan's comment beneath TRomano's answer.

Comment: It appears to be a random, local usage rather that a specific English dialect one.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner American, it's definitely American judging by comments and answers ....

Answer (score 0):

You use "at Christmas" when saying that something happens during the* Christmas holiday period. For example: I'll see you at Christmas.

You say "on Christmas Day" when saying that something happens on December, 25th.  For example: I have to work on Christmas Day. (LONGMAN DICTIONARY).

Comment: You can add a link in your answer, you know. http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/christmas