# Preposition selection for "Are you doing anything special ..... New Year?"

Tags: prepositions

I have another confusing test question:

> Are you doing anything special ..... New Year?"

Possible answers:

> 1. in
> 2. on
> 3. at

If 'New Year' is the period in the begging on the new year then we can use 'in'.

If 'New Year' is the New Year's Day (or the New Year's Eve) the we should use 'on'.

I also suspect that 'the' article should be used before 'New Year'.

Could someone clarify usage of 'New Year'?

Comment: What country is this geared for (or which are you interested in)? My (poor) understanding is that there is a difference between AmE and BrE differ in this case... for example, as an AmE speaker, I might say "What are you doing **for** New Year's" while (I believe) a BrE speaker might say "What are you doing **at** New Year's?".

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109946/what-is-the-difference-between-at-christmas-and-on-christmas

Comment: @Catija it's close but here there is the added question of "on New Year's Eve" vs. "in the New Year".

Comment: @Catija, it doesn't specify what country it is geared for.

Comment: So, the problem is that, if that's the exact text of the test question, you need to find a different book/teacher/whatever. None of those options are valid options.

Comment: @Catija, It is question posted in English learning public group in the Russian social network with few thousands subscribers. I really want to clarify this to all subscribers.

Comment: @Catija "at New Year" (*not* "at New Year's") would be valid in British English, though "What are you doing **on** New Year's Eve" would be more usual, except in Scotland, where the New Year celebrations have their own name: "What are you doing *at Hogmanay*".

Answer (score 3):

(In American English) "New Year's" is short for "New Year's Eve" and is usually capitalized.  "**The** new year" means "this next year" and is usually not capitalized.  Just saying "New Year" is not grammatically complete, and so I wouldn't know for sure which you mean.

All of the following are possible (as well as many other variations):

> What are you doing New Year's (Eve)?
>
> What are you doing **for** New Year's (Eve)?
>
> What are you doing **on** New Year's (Eve)?
>
> What are you doing **for** the new year?
>
> What are you doing **in** the new year?
>
> What are you doing **at** midnight **on** New Year's?

Side note: The first option is the [title of a classic "standard" song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIcuK7wW8bU) that you'll often hear this time of year.

New Year's can also mean "New Year's **Day**", but if you don't specify most people would assume you mean New Year's Eve, because that's when the parties are.

Comment: could 'New Year' without article or possessive be understood as holiday season (like Christmas)?

Comment: @AlexD I would probably understand what you mean, but it's not idiomatic English.  If you want to specify both it's "the Holidays" or "the Holiday Season" (or if you want to be lyrical, ["The most wonderful time of the year"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFtb3EtjEic)).  "New Year's" is specific to that holiday.  Also, I edited my answer to add some additional information.

Comment: I have found following usage examples in Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary "I'm spending New Year in Scotland with my parents.", and in Harrap's Essential English Dictionary "Are you doing anything special for New Year?" (Exact match for my original question).

Comment: @AlexD someone else mentioned that British English might be different, so please consider my suggestions as examples of American English only.

Comment: I don't think your first possibility works without *Eve*—I'm not sure why, but *What are you doing New Year's Eve* sounds OK to my ear (also AmE) but *What are you doing New Year's* sounds completely wrong.

Comment: @1006a I hear it all the time.  It might just be a colloquialism.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty complex question as what you say depends on what you want to convey or ask.

If you're asking what someone is planning for the upcoming year, you'd use "in".

> Are you doing anything special *in* the new year?

Note, in this case, you do need the article.

If you want to ask about someone's plans for New Year's Eve, you could use either "on" or "for", depending on where you are.

> Are you doing anything special *for* New Year's [Eve]?
>   Are you doing anything special *on* New Year's [Eve]?

Note that in this case you will not use the article and, in casual talk, the "Eve" is usually implied, though it can be interpreted to mean "Day" as well, though usually context will tell you which is meant.

I believe that, in British English, you could also use "at" for the above sentence, though it may not work if you're talking about a single day.